# Where is proof that palindrom language is nondeterministic?

Tags: context-free, pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

It is well-known that the language over $T$ with at least 2 symbols is nondeterministic. for simplicity, the language $\{ww^R: w\in\{a,b\}\}$ (even-length palindroms of $a$, $b$) is context-free, but cannot be accepted by any deterministic PDA. The idea of proof is desribed, e.g., by Hopcroft, Ulman, Motwan in 'Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages. and Computation', but I cannot find complete proof. I saw reference for variation of pumping lemma for deterministic CFL, but now cannot find it too.
So. the question: does anyone know where is the proof that the language $\{ww^R: w\in\{a,b\}\}$ is not deterministic?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, now I see reference to Sheng Yu article: [A pumping lemma for deterministic context-free languages](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0020019089901087?via%3Dihub). It can solve my question.

Comment: The original book by Hopcroft and Ullman has a solution of this question using closure properties instead of a special pumping property. The closure property used is one that is valid for DCFL and not for CFL: $\min(L) = \{x ∈ L \mid \text{ no proper prefix of $x$ is in $L$} \}$.

Comment: Hendrik Jan, thanks for reply. Indeed,  the book 'Formal Languages and Their Relation to Automata' states that the language $L=\{ww^R:w\in\Sigma\}$ is not deterministic: Excersice12.6b, with hint to Theorem 12.5 (clousness of dcfl with respect to min and max). However, there is confusing about what is it 'prefix'.  I couldn't find definition of prefix in the book, proper prefix of w is defined as prefix not equal to w. So, with intuitive notion, $\varepsilon$ is prefix of any w,  $\varepsilon\in L$. So, $\min L=\{\varepsilon\}$ is deterministic, and no contradictory is found.

Comment: Your argument is right, but only works if $\varepsilon\in L$. In general $\min L \subseteq L$, words are thrown out if one of their prefixes is also in $L$, see the definition above. So $\min a^*b = a^*b$ as the language contains none of its prefixes. Also $\min \{a^ib^j \mid i\le j\} = \{a^nb^n \mid n\ge 0 \} $.

Comment: Thanks for reply. And what about $L=\{ww^R:w∈\{a,b\}^∗\}$? (By the way, previously ${}^∗$ was errorneously missed.) I see that $\min L=\{ε\}$, because $ε\in L$. So, , $\min L=\{ε\}$ is obviously deterministic. Maybe, Hopcroft and Ulman meant that proper prefix of w is prefix that neigther equal to w nor empty....

Comment: No, H&U do not apply the operation to the $ww^R$ language directly. They first intersect with a well-chosen regular language (which I guess does not contain $\varepsilon$).

Comment: Yep, and it should be something like $a^*bba^*+a^*bba^*bba^*$ (via regular expression). Intersection of dcfl and regular language is dcfl, its min is (hope that I haven't mistaken) $L_0=\{a^nbba^n: n\ge0\}\cup\{a^nbba^mbba^n: n> m\ge0,\}$. Obviously, $L_0$ is not cfl at all (pupmping lemma). So, $ L=\{ww^R:w∈\{a,b\}^∗\}$ is not dcfl. Moreover,  we have a counter-example for a fact that cfl class is not closed with respect to min.